# Ruby on Rails 4 - Using Rake on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I was moving my app from Nitrous.io which uses SQLite to Heroku for production which uses Postgres, and I got the following error.  2 things, I don't get why it won't do change_column, and I definitely don't understand their "hint".  How can I go about implementing properly?

```
-- change_column(:messages, :sender, :integer)                                                                                                    
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "sender" cannot be cast automatically to type integer                                                        
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.                                                                                      
: ALTER TABLE "messages" ALTER COLUMN "sender" TYPE integer
```

The attributes were strings, and I wanted to change to integers so I could reference them.
Any help?
Below is my db migration that it is referencing:

```
class ChangeSenderReceiverToInteger < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column(:messages, :sender, :integer)
    change_column(:messages, :receiver, :integer)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
change_column(:messages, :sender, 'integer USING CAST(sender AS integer)')
```

Ref: http://makandracards.com/makandra/18691-postgresql-vs-rails-migration-how-to-change-columns-from-string-to-integer